# Bit-Count or Hamming-weight of a BitString in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, bitstring, hammingweight

Please how can we `efficiently` calculate the hamming-weight of a bit-string in elixir?

Example: `0b0101101001` has a Hamming-weight of 5 (i.e. 5 bits set)

**My Attempt:**

```
iex> Enum.count(Integer.to_char_list(n,2),&(&1===49))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a better performing solution, which (for me) also shows the intention more clearly:

```
for(<<bit::1 <- :binary.encode_unsigned(n)>>, do: bit) |> Enum.sum
```

Benchmark using benchfella with 100.000 binary digits:

```
Benchfella.start

defmodule HammingBench do
  use Benchfella

  @n Stream.repeatedly(fn -> Enum.random [0, 1] end)
    |> Enum.take(100_000)
    |> Enum.join
    |> String.to_integer(2)

  bench "CharlesO" do
    Enum.count(Integer.to_char_list(@n,2),&(&1===49)) 
  end

  bench "Patrick Oscity" do
    for(<<bit::1 <- :binary.encode_unsigned(@n)>>, do: bit) |> Enum.sum
  end
end
```

Benchmark results:

```
$ mix bench
Compiled lib/hamming_bench.ex
Generated hamming_bench app
Settings:
  duration:      1.0 s

## HammingBench
[20:12:03] 1/2: Patrick Oscity
[20:12:06] 2/2: CharlesO

Finished in 8.4 seconds

## HammingBench
Patrick Oscity         500   4325.79 µs/op
CharlesO                 1   5754094.00 µs/op
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, 500:1 :(

Comment: Please can you shed any light on why your implementation is so much faster, it would really help.

Comment: The slow part of your implementation is converting the integer to a char list. Binary pattern matching on the other hand is highly optimized. However, for a small number of digits the performance difference is negligible.

Comment: Protip: if you put the code in a file `bench/hamming_bench.exs`, you won't need to call `Benchfella.start` manually.

Comment: To anyone reading this who is looking to understand the reasons behind the speedup, see https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/elixir-lang-talk/uKkM0XMDAC0/culTFWF-AgAJ

Answer (score 1):

While *Patrick*'s answer is correct for positive integers, it will fail for negative numbers since [`:binary.encode_unsigned/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#encode_unsigned-1) does not handle them.

### Use `<<>>`

Instead, I would suggest using the Elixir's powerful [`<<>>`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#%3C%3C%3E%3E/1) bitstring operator (which also looks nicer IMO):

```ex
Enum.sum(for << bit::1 <- <<n>> >>, do: bit))
```

You can also specify the integer size as 16-bit, 32-bit, or anything else:

```ex
<<n::integer-32>>
```

---

### Count bits in a single pass

As an alternative approach, you can also count bits directly in one go instead of first fetching all the bits and then summing them:

```ex
defmodule HammingWeight do
  def weight(int) when is_integer(int) do
    w(<<int>>, 0)
  end

  defp w(<<>>>, count),                do: count
  defp w(<<0::1, rest::bits>>, count), do: w(rest, count)
  defp w(<<1::1, rest::bits>>, count), do: w(rest, count + 1)
end
```

---